# What is the difference between "func" and "func()" in TkInter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Python function that takes no parameters. In my code, I call this function twice. Once as a command behind a Tkinter Button and once as a function to an event that I bind to a window. For the command, I call the function as `func` and that works fine. For the event, it will only work if I call it as `func()` and change the definition of the function to be: `func(self)`.

Why? How can I make both these calls compatible?

Comment: could you show us an example code?  just writing `func` does not actually call it so I'd assume you are passing it as the `command` argument to a button but I don't understand how you are using it the second time...

Comment: Briefly: use a variable number of parameters like `*args` or an optional parameter like `event=None`.

Comment: Do you have a small example you can post that shows how you create the button and the event (that is, how you bind the function to the button and event)? `func()` shouldn't work in either of those cases.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because when you bind a function to a button you are not calling the function, only binding it so that `tkinter` knows what to do when the button is pressed. You only need to use `func()` when you are calling the function as you are doing in the the event.

Comment: This has nothing to do with attaching a function to a Button, which does not send an event to the function, and to an event bound to a window, which does send an event. @WhyNot, did this answer actually solve your issue? If it didn't, please note that you are not required to accept an answer, and can unaccept one at any time. Accepting an unhelpful answer will just confuse future readers.